# I get this error when i try importing simple transformers

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, simpletransformers

```
import logging

from simpletransformers.question_answering import QuestionAnsweringModel, QuestionAnsweringArgs
```

i run the above piece of code and get this error

```
> ModuleNotFoundError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_3637/2280022744.py in <module>
>       1 import logging
> ----> 2 from simpletransformers.question_answering import QuestionAnsweringModel, QuestionAnsweringArgs
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpletransformers'
```

even though i have installed simpletransformers

```
!pip install simpletransformers
```

i am using jupyter notebook and i have set my kernel to pytorch

how do i remove this error

Comment: You sure run this in the same virtual environment where you have installed the package?

Comment: Just to double check, can you paste the output of `transformers-cli env` and `pip list | grep simpletransformers`?

Comment: i havent used virtual environment